# How to compare start and end date with current date in php?

Tags: php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $start_date = strtotime($row['start_date']);
    $end_date = strtotime($row['end_date']);
    $current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

    if($start_date <= $current_date && $end_date >= $current_date)
    {
        echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-success'>Start</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-danger'>Over</a>";
    }
}
```

In this code I have two rows where in my first row `start_date = 2019-12-13` and `end_date = 2019-12-20` and second row has `start_date = 2019-12-12` and `end_date = 2019-12-15`. Now, I am simply compare start and end date with current date and show message `start` and `over` but it always show me `start` message only. So, How can I correct if start and end date is not matched with current date.

Comment: Well, since it is the 15th, I would say that both of those rows should show "Start" since you are using `$end_date >= $current_date` if you don't want to include rows that are ending today then you need to use `>`

Comment: Thank You Omn for the help :)

Comment: Is the problem solved or not? Do you need some more guidance? Was it just the typo?